# Correlation of mixed type variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, python, interpretation

I have a Pandas Dataframe with 15 variables. I would like to do some correlation analysis in between all the variables. Typically in pandas I could just call `DataFrame.corr(method)` and pass either `Pearson` or `Spearman` as the method.

In this case my data is mixed type, mostly categorical, some discrete and continuous values and ordinal.

Are there any methods that allow me do see any inter-variable correlations or trends across all data types